# How to check if WooCommerce Product is in a specific category and echo out an image at a specific hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a `do_action('after_product_tabs)` hook that I hope to programmatically echo an image under specific product categories, but I'm running into a bug. I'm able to echo out a `div` as a test for the action hook, but my conditional logic is breaking. Any help would be very much appreciated:

### Here's the function:

```php
function after_product_tabs() {
    do_action('after_product_tabs'); //creates the action hook
};

function display_prewired_image() {
    
    echo '<div class="test" style="clear: both;">'.$home_url.'</div>'; // This prints!
    
    if( has_term( 'strat_pickups', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo' <p>DEBUG ME</p>'; // This breaks
    }
}

add_action('after_product_tabs', 'display_prewired_image');
```

#### I've also Tried:

1.) Passing in Global Variable:

```php
function display_prewired_image() {
    global $product;
    $prod_id = $product->get_id();

    if( has_term( 'strat_pickups', 'product_cat', $prod_id ) ) {
        echo' <p>DEBUG ME</p>';
    }
}
```

2.) Changing the conditional logic from product categories to `is_single()`, which works, so I know my problem is within the logic of `strat_pickups`:

```
function display_prewired_image() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Get product ID
        $prod_id = $product->get_id();
        
        if( is_single('354') ) {
            echo '<h1 style="red!important; clear: both;">DEBUG ME</h1>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No product found!';
    }
}
add_action( 'after_product_tabs', 'display_prewired_image' );
```

---

For more info, I'm customizing the tabs.php template in Woocommerce. Would that not have access to the $product variable?

Comment: I have a customized tabs.php template and am using a custom action hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, global `$product` is missing

```php
function display_prewired_image() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Get product ID
        $prod_id = $product->get_id();
        
        if ( has_term( 'strat_pickups', 'product_cat', $prod_id ) ) {
            echo 'DEBUG ME';
        } else {
            echo 'Category not found!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No product found!';
    }
}
//add_action( 'after_product_tabs', 'display_prewired_image' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_prewired_image' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'display_prewired_image' );
```

Comment: Hmmm... That didn't work either. I failed to mention that I tried using the `$product` variable.

Comment: As a test, I just changed the action hook to `woocommerce_after_single_product` and still, nothing - which is strange. The product category in the body class is `product_cat_strat-pickups`, if that helps anyone.

Comment: I modified the code using the `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form` hook (single product page), 
it works without problems, so if it still doesn't work, the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Is there a way to print errors to a console, like in JS for PHP? I'd love to find out more what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: yes there are and examples of this can be found on stackoverflow, your question is about your code not working, and with my current answer you should be able to situate the problem

Comment: Thanks all for your help so far. I've updated my question. Changing the logic from `has_term()` to `is_single()`, it works. My questions now is, did `has_term()` break in 5.5.1, or do I still have access to the $product variable within the tabs.php template?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. This was a bang your head against the wall moment. The product category was not `strat_pickups`, it was `strat-pickups`.